# First Column values are taking null values place

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have 3 records in pdatatest1:

```
| ID1  | Name1     | Class1 |
|------|-----------|--------|
| 1    | Methushal | 11     |
| 2    | Bush      | 11     |
| 3    | Paul      | 11     |
```

Datelist table is ptable:

```
| iDate      | INAM |
|------------|------|
| 01-06-2022 | AM   |
| 02-06-2022 | AM   |
| 03-06-2022 | AM   |
| 04-06-2022 | AM   |
| 05-06-2022 | AM   |
| 06-06-2022 | AM   |
```

I inserted values are record1:

```
| ID   | Name      | Class | Indate     | Intime   | INAM1 |
|------|-----------|-------|------------|----------|-------|
| 1    | Methushal | 11    | 01-06-2022 | 08:00:00 | P     |
| 1    | Methushal | 11    | 02-06-2022 | 08:00:00 | A     |
| 1    | Methushal | 11    | 03-06-2022 | 08:00:00 | A     |
| 1    | Methushal | 11    | 04-06-2022 | 08:00:00 | P     |
| 1    | Methushal | 11    | 05-06-2022 | 08:00:00 | A     |
```

My SQL Code giving result as below:

```
| dates12    | Name1     | INAM | INAM1 |
|------------|-----------|------|-------|
| 01-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | P     |
| 01-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | P     |
| 01-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | P     |
| 02-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | A     |
| 02-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | A     |
| 02-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | A     |
| 03-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | A     |
| 03-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | A     |
| 03-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | A     |
| 04-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | P     |
| 04-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | P     |
| 04-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | P     |
| 05-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | A     |
| 05-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | A     |
| 05-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | A     |
| 06-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | NULL  |
| 06-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | NULL  |
| 06-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | NULL  |
```

Looking for the result like below:

```
| dates12    | Name1     | INAM | INAM1 |
|------------|-----------|------|-------|
| 01-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | P     |
| 01-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | NULL  |
| 01-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | NULL  |
| 02-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | A     |
| 02-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | NULL  |
| 02-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | NULL  |
| 03-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | A     |
| 03-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | NULL  |
| 03-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | NULL  |
| 04-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | P     |
| 04-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | NULL  |
| 04-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | NULL  |
| 05-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | A     |
| 05-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | NULL  |
| 05-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | NULL  |
| 06-06-2022 | Methushal | AM   | NULL  |
| 06-06-2022 | Bush      | AM   | NULL  |
| 06-06-2022 | Paul      | AM   | NULL  |
```

My sql code is:

```
Select Case when ptable.iDate Is null 
then record1.Indate else ptable.idate end as dates12,
            pdatatest1.Name1, ptable.INAM, record1.INAM1 
into project1
From ptable full Join record1 
on ptable.iDate=record1.Indate,pdatatest1
            Select * From project1
```

And I have another code getting error in sql query I didn't get any result.

```
SELECT iDate dates12,
       Name1,
       INAM,
      (SELECT INAM1
       FROM record1 
       WHERE record1.ID = pdatatest1.ID1
       ) INAM1
FROM pdatatest1
JOIN ptable 
ORDER BY iDate
```

I'm working this in vb.net table SQL Query. Please someone have a look once to correct my code to get correct result which I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cross join and a left join. For example:

```
select a.idate, b.name, a.inam, c.inam1
from ptable a
cross join pdatatest1 b
left join record1 c on c.id = b.id and c.indate = a.idate
```